# How to read String in java that was written using python’s struct.pack method

Tags: java, python, binary, struct

```
out.write( struct.pack(">f", 1.1) );
out.write( struct.pack(">i", 12) );
out.write( struct.pack(">3s", "abc") );
```

how to import struct package in java it says ..

> no package found when i am trying to execute it

so kindly tell me any suggestions if any

Thanking you

i took that code from
[How to read String in java that was written using python's struct.pack method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255918/how-to-read-string-in-java-that-was-written-using-pythons-struct-pack-method)

Answer (score 0):

Read the answer to the question you referenced.  The sample code in the question was incorrect.

Also, you don't import the struct package in Java.  It's a Python package.  Also as described in the other question, you use java.io.DataInputStream to read the file created from Python.

Comment: Is there any equivalent method for struct.pack in java to implement the same functionality
pump_on = struct.pack("IIHHI", 0, 0, 21, 96, 512) 
i am trying to pack a value .. so in java is there function to pack like in python struct.pack function ..
If any suggestions kindly advice me